# Convert UTF-8 encoding in text form to characters

Tags: r, utf-8, utf-16

I have a character string that contains data in UTF-8 encoded form as plain text. Example

```
utf8 = "#C2#BD"
```

I am trying get the character for this value. In this case it would be "`½`"

If this was encoded using UTF-16, it would have been "00BD", I could have converted this into a character that is actually encoded into utf8 by doing

```
intToUtf8(strtoi('0x00BD'))
[1] "½"
```

However I cannot seem to find a way to get the integer value using the utf8 encoded hex "#C2#BD".

Ultimately I want to reach `½` from "#C2#BD". I suspect the path there goes from getting UTF-16 that is convertable into an integer by `strtoi` but I am having a hard time understanding the relationship between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it for that example:

```
utf8chars <- strsplit(utf8, "#")

# just grab the first entry, and leave off the blank
utf8chars <- utf8chars[[1]][-1]

# Convert the hex to integer
utf8int <- strtoi(paste0("0x",utf8chars))

# Then to raw
utf8raw <- as.raw(utf8int)

# And finally to character
utf8char <- rawToChar(utf8raw)

# On Windows you'll also need this
Encoding(utf8char) <- "utf-8"
```

Real examples shouldn't require much in the way of changes...

Comment: `utf8chars[[1]][-1]` is better for generalizability ("#E2#86#92"")